# URL.openConnection() returns already-open connection the second time

Tags: java, scala, httpurlconnection

I'm working on a website-scraping application in Scala.  The site I'm scraping is heavily session-oriented, so I have to hit the site once to get a session ID before I can do anything else.

I get the connection for retrieving the session ID like this:

```
url.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
```

It works fine.  The .connected field of the returned HttpURLConnection is false, and it flips to true when I call .connect() on it.  No problem.

The first hint of trouble occurs when I finish with the connection and call .disconnect() on it.  The .connected field stays true.  Hm.

So now I've got my session ID, and I go to get the page that has the form I want on it.  I call

```
url.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
```

again, just like last time--same code, in fact--except this time the HttpURLConnection it gives me has the .connected field set to true!  I thought at first that somehow it was giving me the same object it gave me before, but no, the memory ID is different.

So of course now when I call .setRequestProperty() on the connection, it blows up with an IllegalStateException: Already connected.

Am I misunderstanding how to use HttpURLConnection?

Notes: Scala 2.9.2, Java 6.0.  Also, the URL objects on which I call .openConnection() are different objects, not the same.

Thanks...

Comment: I have the same issue. Strangely, it seems to occur on some VMs and not others - I haven't spotted a pattern. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's called connection pooling, in quest of HTTP Keep-alive. It's good. You want it. If you really don't, call the `disconnect()` method.

Comment: I _am_ calling .disconnect(): see original post.  It leaves the .connected field strangely unmolested.

Comment: I have nothing against my HttpURLConnections being pooled: I just want to be able to set request parameters on them more than just the first time I connect one.

Comment: @DanWiebe I'd surprised if that doesn't work already, it's a pretty basic usage pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The `URL` class is not well suited for session based work (especially cookie based sessions) in my experience.

If you want to take advantage of this, I'd suggest using something like [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

IMHO

Comment: The sessions aren't cookie-based, they're parameter based.

I'd like to keep this pretty lightweight, if I can.  What I'm doing is simple enough that I'd rather not bring in heavy artillery like HTTPClient.

Comment: Yeah, no worries, it's only a suggestion :)

Comment: I disagree with this comment. URLConnection handles cookies incorrectly when redirecting, but otherwise works fine. I've done quite a bit of work with it (e.g. http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client) and found this out the hard way. The Apache API might be a good choice for a scraping tool but only if you're happy with its imposed thread pool.

Comment: @Rick-777 It's good to know, I've never been able to get it to work, must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like HttpUrlConnection is [keeping the connection alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) for you under the covers.

Take a look [at this article](http://www.tikalk.com/java/forums/httpurlconnection-disable-keep-alive) for some tips to force it to close the connection and not be overly helpful.

Although in your case it sounds like you might want to use keep-alive, as it could speed up your calls to the website by avoiding unnecessary connection handshakes.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I tried it: .setRequestProperty ("Connection", "close").  Didn't work, though: same stuff.

I appreciate your suggestion, though.

Comment: are you also closing any streams from the connection you are reading?

Comment: Yup, sure am, but thanks for checking.

It seems inexcusable under any circumstances that you would ask for a fresh HttpURLConnection and be given one that's already connected.  I can't think of any scenario where that should be acceptable.